# Preencher próximos campos a partir de um input ou select preenchido PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Sou novo por aqui e iniciante em PHP, mas estou fazendo um projeto onde preciso preencher alguns input's do formulário com dados vindo do banco de dados a partir de um input ou select já preenchido anteriormente.

Meu banco usuário contém 4 colunas: ip, usuario, setor e homeOffice

Já o meu formulário (index.php) tem:

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="inputWlan">Wlan</label>
          <input type="text" name="inputWlan" class="form-control" id="inputWlan"
              placeholder="192.168.1." disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
          <label for="inputIp">IP</label>
          <input type="text" name="inputIp" class="form-control" id="inputIp"
              placeholder="IP">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <label for="inputUsuario">Usuário</label>
          <input type="text" name="inputUsuario" class="form-control"
              id="inputUsuario" disabled>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputSetor">Setor</label>
          <input type="text" name="inputSetor" class="form-control"
              id="inputSetor" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="inputHomeOffice">Home Office</label>
          <input type="text" name="inputHomeOffice" class="form-control"
              id="inputHomeOffice" disabled>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Fiz algumas tentativas com Javascript mas sempre tem dado erro dizendo que $.getJSON não é uma função, como segue a seguir o código em JS

Nome do Arquivo personalizado.js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='inputIp']").blur(function () {
        var $usuario = $("input[name='inputUsuario']");
        var $setor = $("input[name='inputSetor']");
        var $homeOffice = $("input[name='inputHomeOffice']");
        var ip = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("functionUsuario.php", { ip },
            function (retorno) {
                $usuario.val(retorno.usuario);
                $setor.val(retorno.setor);
                $homeOffice.val(retorno.homeOffice);
            });
    });
});
```

E no código em PHP (functionUsuario.php) fiz a coleta dos dados do banco de dados retornando um JSON para esse mesmo Javascript

```html
<?php

include_once("../../../config/conexaodb.php");

function retorna($ip, $conn) {
    $search = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE ip = '$ip' LIMIT 1"); 
    if($search->num_rows) {
        $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);
        $valores['usuario'] = $row_usuario['usuario'];
        $valores['setor'] = $row_usuario['setor'];
        $valores['homeOffice'] = $row_usuario['homeOffice'];
    } else {
        $valores['usuario'] = 'Informações não encontradas';
    }

    return json_encode($valores);
}

if(isset($_GET['inputIp'])) {
    echo retorna($_GET['inputIp'], $conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn)
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse caso?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

você ja incluiu o arquivo jquery na sua pagina principal, de preferencia antes do personalizado.js, se ainda nao, adicione a linha abaixo no antes de qualquer JavaScript no seu HTML.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```